# Space in image url returning broken image for certain devices alone

Tags: android, image, url, fresco

I am working on an android app which uses FRESCO image loading library. I display images from the server in grid layouts. It so happened that image url's for a certain album had space included in the url.

The images were loaded properly in certain devices like

1. Moto g5s plus-(android 7.1-Nougat)
2. nexus 6(android 7.0) and a few more.

Whereas it failed to load the images on devices like

1. Moto g3(Android 6.0.1-marshmallow) and a few samsung devices.

Can somebody tell me why it worked on certain devices of the same manufacturer but failed on a few.

Glide did seem to load the url's with space in Moto g3 which failed with fresco.

I understand that I'm supposed to encode the url to avoid such mishaps but I'm just curious as to why it failed on certain devices when using fresco ,Is it based on android versions?